# Running a Java application on a machine that doesn't have a JVM

Tags: jvm, java

I have created an .exe file of my software (which is a Java swing application). But the .exe file is running only on those computers which have the JVM installed. I want to run it on computers which do not have the JVM installed. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: "I finally have created the exe file of my software(in java swings).But the exe file is running only on those computers which haveJVM installed.."  You can run this 'exe' on Macs. & *nix boxes with Java?!?  BTW - those words are 'Java' & 'Swing', note the caps. and non-plurality (singularity) of both words.

Comment: You can bundle JRE JVM runtime in your application installer (Launch4J, NSIS, InnoSetup, IzPack can help you with this) and make your application run from bundled JRE JVM runtime folder if your setup installer design doesn't opt for optional JRE download support. Other than that, if Internet is available on the client side, you can use Java Web Start approach provided that your application hosting server is ready.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need a JVM to run Java.  There's no getting around that.

Users that don't have a JRE installed will have to get one.  Don't confuse that with the JDK.  They don't need all the development tools, just the runtime engine.

Comment: Some apps distribute a JRE with the app (e.g. SoapUI).  This makes the download many times larger and architecture specific but insures that it will run out of the box.  In this case you may want to provide two or more downloads, some with JRE some without.

Comment: For windows there are also some .exe jar wrapper programs that will embed your jar in a native binary that checks for an installed JVM and prompt the user to download and install from Sun(oracle) if not present. Sort of like how .Net apps can prompt user to install the .Net libraries if not present. I haven't looked into those in a long time though so I don't have a good recommendation or if this has fallen out of favor. I just remember in the early days of swing this behavior was a common feature request.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to ship JVM with your application one way or another anyway. So why not include JRE into the installation bundle?

Another option would be creating an installer that will download JRE automatically from the Internet if it isn't installed. For example you might want to check out this guide http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Java_Launcher_with_automatic_JRE_installation (but read about NSIS first if you're unfamiliar with it).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what application you used for wrapping the jar as an exe but I recommend you to use **[Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)** which is a wrapper who can check if the user has already installed JRE/JDK before trying to execute the application and if it doesn't it will display a message and open the browser to download java.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [deployJava.js](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) to help ensure the user has the minimum version of Java needed to run the app.
2. Launch the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

This should work on systems for which Java is available (i.e. not just Windows).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this, give [GCJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java) a look. Bear in mind however that AWT / Swing support, amongst many other things is pretty much dead.

Even if you won't lose anything in terms of language features, before you go plummeting ahead stop and think if this is something you really need. The vast majority of users have Java and by using GCJ to compile to machine code you're missing all the potential hotspot optimisations, creating a much bigger footprint in a lot of cases and losing cross-platform compatibility.

It's perfectly acceptable to distribute a jar file and then direct your users to download the JDK if they haven't already, and unless you're doing something very specialised it's what I'd recommend in this case.